# Как по аналогии сделать проверку на диагональ?

Tags: python, массивы, циклы

Здраствуйте у меня вопрос. Я делал код для крестиков ноликов сказали сделать самый простой. Но потом как доп. задание сказали его оптимизировать. Я сумел оптимизировать проверку победы но только на горизонталь и вертикаль. И у меня возникла сложность как сделать диагональ. Буду благодарен если сможете помочь. Вот цикл проверки

```
field = [['_'] * 3, ['_'] * 3, ['_'] * 3]

for i in range(len(field)-1):
    values = {field[i][c] for c in range(len(field[i]))}
    if len(values) == 1 and '_' not in values:
        print(field[i][0])
    values = {field[r][i] for r in range(len(field))}
    if len(values) == 1 and '_' not in values:
        print(field[0][i])
```

Answer (score 0):

Обход элементов главной диагонали:

```
for i in range(len(field)):
    if field[i][i]==.....
```

Обход элементов обратной диагонали:

```
for i in range(len(field)):
    if field[i][len(field)-i-1]==...
```

Ну а далее -  проверяйте что хотите.

Comment: Не оптимально. Можно же break влепить, либо через while. А еще диагоналей например не бывает без угловых заполненых полей, я бы их в первую очередь проверял к примеру.

Comment: Можно конечно. Как можно это-же сделать и в исходном коде. Но про оптимизацию кода речь не идет вроде. Тем более, что исходя из вопроса и задания я даже не уверен, что ТС знает, что такое break. Ну а во-вторых, я же написал  как перебирать элементы диагоналей, причем не зависимо от того, какой размерности матрица. Но я не брался решать задачу полностью вместо ТС,