# Взять побочную диагональ массива

Tags: numpy

#Как взять побочную (противоположную) диагональ массива? Требуется изменить обе диагонали массива на единицы

```
my_array = np.zeros((7, 7))
d = np.diag_indices(7)
my_array[d] = 1

[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1.]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Если массив состоит только из нулей, а не каких либо других значений, то можно сделать следующими тремя способами:

1. При помощи функции [`np.fliplr()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fliplr.html), позволяющей перевернуть массив относительно оси X и представить главную диагональ как побочную и наоборот;
2. При помощи [`np.flip(my_array, axis=1)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html), по сути делающая то же самое при помощи аргументов;
3. При помощи срезов: `my_array[:,::-1]` — это если забавы ради :)

```py
import numpy as np

my_array = np.zeros((7, 7))
d = np.diag_indices(7)
my_array[d] = 1
np.fliplr(my_array)[d] = 1
# my_array[:,::-1][d] = 1
# np.flip(my_array, axis=1)[d] = 1

print(my_array)
```

Если говорить про общие решения, то могу предложить, например, развернуть второй член кортежа:

```py
import numpy as np

my_array = np.zeros((7, 7))
d = np.diag_indices(7)
my_array[d] = 1
d = d[0], d[1][::-1]
my_array[d] = 1

print(my_array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну вы перед тем как вопрос задавать - прочитайте этот форум ну хоть бы за три предыдущих дня.
Вот ваша задача и ваш ответ:

[Как по аналогии сделать проверку на диагональ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1417465)